# How to use wget in an Expect script?

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, expect

I first download a file to `/root/TRY1/`:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
cd /root/TRY1/
exec wget --http-user $user --http-password $password $url
```

Then I want to extract the file:

```
cd /root/TRY1/
exec bash -c "tar -xzvf /root/TRY1/BigDataProtector*.tgz"
```

However, this just downloads the file in that location and stops after that. The file isn't extracted.

But when I comment the wget part and run the extract command it does get extracted.

How do I make both the commands consecutively?

Answer (score 3):

Use Expect's native `spawn` command:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
cd /root/TRY1/
spawn wget --http-user $user --http-password $password $url
spawn bash -c "tar -xzvf /root/TRY1/BigDataProtector*.tgz"
```

Or prevent `wget` from writing to the terminal with `--quiet` argument:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
cd /root/TRY1/
exec wget --quiet --http-user $user --http-password $password $url
exec bash -c "tar -xzvf /root/TRY1/BigDataProtector*.tgz"
```

---

`wget`'s progress bar causes Expect to fail when it is called with `exec`.